# counting rows as new column then sum

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with rows like this:

| guildname | rank | name | season |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GuildOne | 1 | Player1 | 10 |
| GuildOne | 3 | Player2 | 10 |
| GuildOne | 30 | Player3 | 10 |
| GuildTwo | 7 | Player4 | 10 |
| GuildTwo | 9 | Player5 | 10 |
| GuildTwo | 31 | Player6 | 10 |
| GuildThree | 63 | Player7 | 10 |
| GuildThree | 393 | Player8 | 10 |
| GuildThree | 99 | Player9 | 10 |
| GuildOne | 216 | Player10 | 10 |

I want to be able to get the points per guild based on their player's rank as follows:

- rank >=1 && rank <= 150 : 4
- rank >=151 && rank <= 300 : 2
- rank >=301 && rank <= 600 : 1

and would like the resulting table to be:

| guildname | rank1to150 | rank151to300 | rank301up | sumofpoints | rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GuildOne | 3 | 1 | 0 | 14 | 1 |
| GuildTwo | 3 | 0 | 0 | 12 | 2 |
| GuildThree | 2 | 0 | 1 | 7 | 3 |

This is what I have so far:

```sql
WITH mpguildpoints (
  guildname,
  points,
  season
) AS (
    select mp_rankings.guildname,
    case when mp_rankings.rank >= 1 AND mp_rankings.rank <= 150 then 4
    when mp_rankings.rank >= 151 AND mp_rankings.rank <= 300 then 2
    when mp_rankings.rank >= 300 AND mp_rankings.rank <= 600 then 1
    end as points,
    season
    from mp_rankings
    group by mp_rankings.guildname,mp_rankings.rank,mp_rankings.season
    order by points desc, season desc
)

select guildname, count(points), sum(points) as totalpoints from mpguildpoints
where season = 10
group by guildname,points
order by totalpoints desc
```

Comment: Take `mp_rankings.rank` out of your first `group by`, and remove `points` from your second `group by`.

Comment: @MikeOrganek I'm getting this eror `Failed to run sql query: column "mp_rankings.rank" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: Sorry--I focused on your query rather than you desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use range operators, aggregation filters, and window functions:

```
with pointcalc as (
  select guildname, 
         case
           when int4range(1, 150, '[]')   @> rank then 4
           when int4range(151, 300, '[]') @> rank then 2
           when int4range(301, 600, '[]') @> rank then 1
           else 0
         end as points
    from rankings
), counts_sum as (
  select guildname, 
         count(1) filter (where points = 4) as rank1to150,
         count(1) filter (where points = 2) as rank151to300,
         count(1) filter (where points = 1) as rank301to600,
         sum(points) as sumofpoints
    from pointcalc
   group by guildname
)
select *, 
       rank() over (order by sumofpoints desc)
  from counts_sum
 order by rank;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=797587e9cff9700037d9187aed74d702)*

Comment: this works like a charm. just needs a bit of adjustment but I was able to get what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost near on your query, just need to do `joins` for the **ranking**.

```
select t1.guildname
    , t2.ct as rank1to150
    , t3.ct as rank151to300
    , t4.ct as rank301up
    , t1.totalpoints
    , t1.ct as "rank"
from 
    (select guildname, count(points) ct, sum(points) as totalpoints from mpguildpoints
    where season = 10
    group by guildname, points) t1
left join
    (select guildname, count(1) ct from mp_rankings
    where season = 10 and rank between 1 and 150
    group by guildname) t2 on t2.guildname = t1.guildname
left join
    (select guildname, count(1) ct from mp_rankings
    where season = 10 and rank between 151 and 300
    group by guildname) t3 on t3.guildname = t1.guildname   
left join
    (select guildname, count(1) ct from mp_rankings
    where season = 10 and rank > =301 
    group by guildname) t4 on t4.guildname = t1.guildname   
order by t1.rank asc
```

Comment: do I just plug this after the CTE? because if I do it's throwing an error `Failed to validate sql query: syntax error at or near "from"`

Comment: @kams, try again

Answer (score 0):

Put each condition in a `CASE` expression and perform conditional aggregation:

> ```
> with a (guildname, playerrank, name, season) as (
>   select *
>   from(values
> ('GuildOne', 1, 'Player1', 10),
> ('GuildOne', 3, 'Player2', 10),
> ('GuildOne', 30, 'Player3', 10),
> ('GuildTwo', 7, 'Player4', 10),
> ('GuildTwo', 9, 'Player5', 10),
> ('GuildTwo', 31, 'Player6', 10),
> ('GuildThree', 63, 'Player7', 10),
> ('GuildThree', 393, 'Player8', 10),
> ('GuildThree', 99, 'Player9', 10),
> ('GuildOne', 216, 'Player10', 10)
>   ) as t
> )
> select
>   b.*,
>   dense_rank() over(order by score desc) as rank_
> from (
> select
>   guildname,
>   /*Count per group    */
>   count(1) filter(where playerrank between 1 and 150) as rank1to150, 
>   count(1) filter(where playerrank between 151 and 300) as rank151to300, 
>   count(1) filter(where playerrank between 301 and 600) as rank300up, 
>   sum(
>     case
>       /*Case stops on the first TRUE branch*/
>       when playerrank <= 150 then 4
>       when playerrank <= 300 then 2
>       when playerrank <= 600 then 1
>     end
>   ) as score
>   from a
> group by 1
> ) as b
> ```
>
> ```
> guildname  | rank1to150 | rank151to300 | rank300up | score | rank_
> :--------- | ---------: | -----------: | --------: | ----: | ----:
> GuildOne   |          3 |            1 |         0 |    14 |     1
> GuildTwo   |          3 |            0 |         0 |    12 |     2
> GuildThree |          2 |            0 |         1 |     9 |     3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=df8b97194babb8de9752b754f6cc79d7)*